# Shopify: How to show up-sell products before going checkout process

Tags: node.js, express, shopify-app

I am new on Shopify development. I am developing an app which will show products before the checkout process to the user. For that, I am using node-express. 
Currently, I have done with app creation & installation on Shopify store and get access token but I couldn't be able to find a way to modify the checkout process as like my case to Show up-selling products to the user via the application.

I will be very thankful if someone guides me to know how can I achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You do not show Upsell on the checkout, at that point is too late in any sense to do anything. In a Plus shop you could alter checkout, but the scripting you can do in checkout is not flush with options.

Instead, you write all your upsell code at the add to cart event level for products, or the checkout event at the cart level. In both cases, you are free to upsell products and you have access to your App and it's rich logic via an App Proxy, allowing you to make JS XHR calls for your upsells. This pattern is exploited by many, so be brave, you are not mining any virgin ground.